Йотація при збігу голосних
Наскільки мені відомо, що збіг голосних звуків українській не дуже притаманний і десь чув про йотацію голосних. Не можу знайти нічого по цій темі тепер. Переважно пишу діялект, геніяльно, варіянт замість діалект, геніально, варіант.
І от цікаво, чи йотація можлива лише у випадку, коли перша голосна є "і" чи при інших голосних, і на яких підставах? (на рівні говірки також можна)

Трошки поправив форматування і прописав теги. Загалом, цікава тема, але дуже бажано під час створення запитання демонструвати ознаки власної спроби знайти відповідь. «Не можу нічого знайти» — не є такою ознакою, якщо що. :) Без цього запитання виглядатиме занадто загальним, і відповідь на нього вимагатиме написання цілої статті (що не є добре).

Так, словянські [і не лише] мови взагалому не любять гіатус чи зïяння — наукове визначїннє згаданого вами виразу як збіг голосних звуків. Про всяк зазначу, що це стосуєʼся збігів не лише всерединї слів, а і між їми, тому прийменники і похідні від їх приростки часто пари, де додаєʼся і: в ~ ві, з ~ зі ітд; або їхнїй чи поруч слова сусїднїй голосний можуть сьʼутрачати. Ось декотрі приклади з Термінологія гуманітарних знань від Мирослава Гнатюка: не [о]днимай, роб[и]; також від Афереза із суфіксацією у варіантах власних імен жителів волинського Полісся від Нестерчука: [О]леся, [І]лля, [А]ліна ітд. Декотрі стали і стандартними словами: біло[о]брисий, довго[о]бразий ітд. Крім вставного й можеʼ бути також в → па[в]ук, а на початку слова також г → [г]орїх, і → [і]мла, (діалектне) л → [л]отава. Вони ж можуть і випадати, навіть якщо вони частина слова — [в]орона, [г]орох. На додачу, декотрі букви, насамперед в ~ у і й ~ і, можуть змінювати свою вимову в залежностї сусїднїх звуків.
Про всяк зазначу, декотрі слова можуть мати певні звуки не як вставні, а саме як частину слова. Наприклад досить славнозвісне слово проєкт, котре декотрим можеʼ бути відомим як проект, має корїнь єкт, тобто тут йотації немаʼ, тому і об·єкт, ін·єкц·ія ітд; іншомовні слова тому теж приклад, де й, де буква зберегла свій вигляд як j, став іншим звуком: анґл. про·джект або фр. про·жект·ор, для порівняня Й[в]ан там Джон i Жан відповідно.
Тож, як можна було зрозуміти з першого абзацу, йотація — лише один з інструментів уникання зïяння. Щодо того, де йотація можеʼ ся-проявяти:

початковий і — згаданий вами випадок; хіба зазначу, що часто:

на початку слова такий конструкт одразу йотуєʼся без жодних вставок, нп. іудей → юдей;

подібний конструкт стаєʼ як (ь)й + відповідний голосний: мільйон, серйоз; або просто ь без й + відповідний голосний: Наталя; подеколи і з подовжїнням попереднього приголосного, але це в переважно питомих словах: життя.



не бачу перешкод і для зворотнього явища, тобто кінцевого і, відповідно ж записуєʼся як ї, тому езуїт, протеїн, коїтус; можу також зазначити про існування піїт з новоґрецького ποιητής проти поет і що поєднуєʼ ций пункт з попереднїм;


Очїкую побачити і для гиншого переднього голосного звука е:

на початку: ідея, лоґейон, приклад з ею поки не знайшов, це ще ускладнюється тим, що тут у радше нескладове в, але не бачу перешкод, бо з попереднїх прикладів видно, що зі гиншими заднїми голосними сполучаєʼ; можна зазначити, що зворотнє до ґео- не знайшов, але, ради справедливостї, відома богиня таки Ґея чи Ґая.

в кінцї, де очевидно стаєʼ як є: ґеєна [що включаєʼ і попереднїй пункт]; нестандартізовані, але натрапляють ся: маєстро (в різних часах і місцях), інфлуєнца, каноє — втч і до гурта, що офіційно звеʼ ся Один в каное, також напрапяв на запис в каної в цьому контекстї, а не як ґеоґрафічної одиницї; щодо останнього слова, то цїлком можливо, що добра частка запису насамперед через те, що пишуть за звичкою є замість э — вони на одній клавішї.


Лишилиʼся лише заднї голосні. Тут вже насправдї дещо складнїше знайти, пак тут очікую за вставного радше в (наприклад можна зустрїти какао → какаво, або згадати па[в]ук). Підстава досить проста: й це близький родич і, цим зазвичай і пояснюється зміна чергування о і е після якостї попереднього звуку: місяць → місяцехід, але снігохід; водою, але ляля → лялею чи край → краєм ітд.
Але все ж на щоʼсь можна натрапити і тут:

кінцеве а, тобто я: статуя, [натянуто, бо в оріґіналї Zoe] Зоя;

кінцеве о можеʼ мати проблеми пошуку в гісторічному контекстї, бо йо могло передавати ся записом по різному, але можна натрапити на фарайон щонайменше в декількох наукових творах в контекстї Угорської Русї (гинші назви: Підкарпатська чи просто Картпатська Русь) від Гнатюка чи Жатковича;

крім згаданого вище явища, кінцеве у маєʼ додаткову проблему — латінські закінчення як um і us зазвичай викидають, а й додають, часом перетворюють взагалї на жїночий рід, тобто а додають: алуміній, музей, лабораторія, студія, крітерій, ґімназія, стіпендія ітд. Там де подвійний у — частїше бачу злиття в один у, як це було з о вище [на початку]: вакум, індивідум [нагадаю, просто індивід теж є], континум ітд.


